# How do you replace multiple carriage return / newline with a single carriage return?

Tags: powershell

Within the textbox; I coded when the textbox lost it's focus then trigger the event to remove multiple carriage returns and newline with a single return and newline.

I tried a switch, it works, but I'll need a loop. Once match found and replaced; it won't continue the rest.

I tried a while; but it continues none stop.

I tried a leave event, but it's like the switch code.

Switch:

```
Switch($Textbox1.text -eq "`r`n`r`n`r`n"){
    $TextBox1.text = $TextBox1.text -replace "`r`n`r`n`r`n", "`r`n`r`n"
}
```

While:

```
While($Textbox1.text -match "`r`n`r`n`r`n"){
    $TextBox1.text = $TextBox1.text -replace "`r`n`r`n`r`n", "`r`n`r`n"
}
```

Leave event:

```
$TextBox1.add_leave({

    $TextBox1.text = $TextBox1.text -replace "`r`n`r`n`r`n", "`r`n`r`n"

})
```

For example,

abc

(5 returns/Newline)

abc

(7 returns/Newline)

abc

When the textbox lost its focus then the code trigger then the result should be:

abc

(1 return/newline)

abc

(1 return/newline)

abc

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You just put `Exit` where you want to stop and get out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$action = { $TextBox1.text -replace "(`r`n){2,}","`r`n" }


$TextBox1.add_leave( $action )
```

Comment: thanks. However that did not work. I built it into a function and it worked.

        Function action{$TextBox1.text = $TextBox1.text -replace "(`r`n){2,}","`r`n`r`n"}

        $TextBox1.add_leave({action})

Comment: However, I do like for you to explain the {2,} part and educate me on that.